# Generating unique token on the fly with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to generate a token in my controller for a user in the "user_info_token" column. However, I want to check that no user currently has that token. Would this code suffice?

```
  begin
    @new_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64 
    user = User.find_by_user_info_token(@new_token) 
  end while user != nil 

  @seller.user_info_token = @new_token
```

Or is there a much cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The cleanest solution I found:

```
@seller.user_info_token = loop do
  token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  break token unless User.exists?(user_info_token: token)
end
```

And something very clean but with potential duplicates (very few though):

```
@seller.user_info_token = SecureRandom.uuid
```

[Random UUID probability of duplicates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates)

Edit: of course, add a unique index to your `:user_info_token`. It will be much quicker to search for a user with the same token **and** it will raise an exception if by chance, 2 users are saved at the exact same moment with the exact same token!

Answer (score 56):

**If** your token is long enough and generated by a cryptographically secure [pseudo-]random number generator, then you do **not** need to verify that the token is unique. You do **not** need to generate tokens in a loop.

16 raw source bytes is long enough for this effective guarantee. When formatted for URL-safety, the result will be longer.

```
# Base-64 (url-safe) encoded bytes, 22 characters long
SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(16)

# Base-36 encoded bytes, naturally url-safe, ~25 characters long
SecureRandom.hex(16).to_i(16).to_s(36)

# Base-16 encoded bytes, naturally url-safe, 32 characters long
SecureRandom.hex(16)
```

This is because the probability that the 16-byte or 128-bit token is nonunique is so vanishingly small that it is virtually zero. There is only a [50% chance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Square_approximation) of there being any repetitions after approximately 2<sup>64</sup> = 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 = 1.845 x 10<sup>19</sup> tokens have been generated. If you start generating one billion tokens per second, it will take approximately 2<sup>64</sup>/(10<sup>9</sup>*3600*24*365.25) = 600 *years* until there is a 50% chance of there having occurred any repetitions at all.

But you're not generating one billion tokens per second. Let's be generous and suppose you were generating one token per second. The time frame until a 50% chance of even one collision becomes *600 billion years*. The planet will have been swallowed up by the sun long before then.

Comment: +1 This should be the accepted answer. It is correct, elegant and simple — and backed by logical practicality.

Comment: Very well said.  I have only one minor nitpick.  When you say "When formatted for URL-safety, the result will be longer."  But that doesn't make the probability of duplicates any lower.  The base64 encoding algorithm is reversible and deterministic, so the fact that the base64-encoded token is longer does not make it any more random or unique since two input keys will always base64 encode to the same output key.  I'm not sure if you were implying that the increased length of the base64 output meant it was more random or not, apologies if I misinterpreted.  But I just wanted to point this out.

Answer (score 4):

I have many models I apply unique tokens to. For this reason I've created a `Tokened` concern in `app/models/concerns/tokened.rb`

```
module Tokened

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    after_initialize do
      self.token = generate_token if self.token.blank?
    end
  end

  private
    def generate_token
      loop do
        key = SecureRandom.base64(15).tr('+/=lIO0', 'pqrsxyz')
        break key unless self.class.find_by(token: key)
      end
    end
end
```

In any model I want to have unique tokens, I just do

```
include Tokened
```

But yes, your code looks fine too.

Comment: but self sets the token for current_user right? Because here I have @seller and current_user as two different users. How would I do it in that case?

Comment: My code above affects any newly created model instance *(or any model loaded from the database which doesn't already have a token set)* who's class is including the `Tokened` model.

Answer (score 2):

Rails 5 comes with this feature, you only need to add to your model the next line:

```
class User
  has_secure_token
end
```

Since Rails 5 is not releases yet you can use the [has_secure_token](http://github.com/robertomiranda/has_secure_token) gem. Also you can see my blog post to see more info about it https://coderwall.com/p/kb97gg/secure-tokens-from-rails-5-to-rails-4-x-and-3-x

Comment: Will this not work with rails4 without the gem? It's in the `master` for rails https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/secure_token.rb

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do something using the actual time. Then you won't need to check if the token was already used by an user.

```
new_token = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(Time.now.to_i.to_s + rand(999999999).to_s)
user.user_info_token = new_token
```

Comment: Passing in times, random strings, or any other 'changing' data into md5 doesn't help it to avoid a collision.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some below tricks to get unique token, its so easy which I used in my project -

```
CREDIT_CHARS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"

def create_credit_key(count = 25)
    credit_key = ""
    key = CREDIT_CHARS.length
    for i in 1..count
      rand = Random.rand((0.0)..(1.0))
      credit_key += CREDIT_CHARS[(key*rand).to_i].to_s
    end 
    return credit_key
  end
```

Using digest it is again more easy, here I tried to generate without using any algorithm.